# Kotlin Split a List of Model into another List of Models

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I am working on a project which looks simple but I am blocked on an issue.
I receive from an api a list of music titles which contains an albumId, an Id and the title.
The data class will look like this :

```
data class Title(
    val albumId: Int,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String)
```

I have created a data class called Album :

```
data class Album (
    val albumId: Int,
    val titles: List<Title>
)
```

I want to split my

```
List<Title>
```

to create a

```
List<Album>
```

by splitting by albumId. How would you manage this ?
Thanks for your feed back.

Answer (score 2):

```
data class Title(
  val albumId: Int,
  val id: Int,
  val title: String
)

data class Album(
  val albumId: Int,
  val titles: List<Title>
)

val titles = listOf(
  Title(1, 1, "Abc 1"),
  Title(1, 2, "Abc 2"),
  Title(2, 1, "Def 1"),
  Title(2, 2, "Def 2"),
  Title(2, 3, "Def 3")
)

val albums = titles
  .groupBy { it.albumId }
  .map { (albumId, titles) -> Album(albumId, titles) }

albums.forEach(::println)
```